# Camelbak bottle VS sticker remover

Tags: cleaning

I used sticker remover liquid to get some sticker glue off my camelbak chute bottle. Glue did come off, and left a coating of rough white residue. This can be seen on the following photos. 
When scratching it on its thickest point with my nail, it does go away a bit. Any suggestions what this is, and how to remove it?

(photos were too big to attach)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwWW_3znHFp7eXU3ZkdHTS1OS1E

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwWW_3znHFp7alpwdEkzT2pLTnM

Comment: Use a bit of toothpaste on a moist wad of cotton to polish the plastic clear again where spirits have whitened the plastic. The toothpaste works as a fine-grit polishing compound.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [rubbing alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbing_alcohol) to remove stickers in the future. The [white spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit) appears to have altered the plastic of the bottle. Rubbing alcohol can remove sticker glue without affecting most plastics.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common thing to happen. If the material is rubber/ plastic based, immersing it into hot water could help. You can try scrubbing it of while the area is submerged in hot water. Please note that the bottle is resistant to hot water. Also, do not over heat the water as it may damage the bottle, as well as burn your hand. The paper residue might not vanish instantly. You might have to do this a couple of times. The residue should vanish after a few days of usage.

Also, I would advice you not to scratch it off using anything points, as you may end up damaging the bottle, or leaving on it scratch marks.

Another way into to moisten the area and **Gently** use sandpaper. But, then again be careful you don't damage the bottle.

Comment: Will give this a try. I tried using white spirit, and it looked 100% clean for about a minute, then turned back to how it looked before..

Comment: I'm not sure this is 100% effective, but I've seen my grandmother use this method to take of labels from bottle. Worth a shot :)